# Joining two queries

Tags: db2

All, Need a help with joining data from two select statement in DB2.

First query is,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(EMPLOYEENAME)
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B, TABLE3 C
WHERE A.EMPLOYEEID=B.EMPLOYEEID AND B.EMPLOYEENUM=C.EMPLOYEENUM
```

Now, the result from **first query EMPLOYEENAME** need to be joined with second query

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE4 D, TABLE5 E, **FIRSTQUARYRESULT**.F
AND D.EMPLOYEENAME=E.EMPLOYEENAME AND E.EMPLOYEENAME= F.EMPLOYEENAME
```

Any lead how we can achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using SQL Server or DB2?  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: I am not very familiar with DB2, but in most other SQLs you can replace your **FIRSTQUERYRESULT** with a subquery. SELECT * FROM TABLE4 D, TABLE5 E, (SELECT DISTINCT(EMPLOYEENAME) FROM TABLE1 A) F WHERE D.EMPLOYEENAME = E.EMPLOYEENAME AND E.EMPLOYEENAME = F.EMPLOYEENAME;

Comment: He's asking if you are using db2 or Microsoft SQL Server.  You tagged your question with both.

Comment: Sorry, Changed it.. I am using DB2

Comment: @gmiley - as near as I know, that's standard syntax and works in any RDBMS.  user3657257 - Actually, I'm more concerned about the fact that you seem to be using a name for the join (which you're demonstrating is not unique), among other things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick :

**STEP 1 : //Insert data of the first query in a temp table**
INSERT INTO temptable 
SELECT DISTINCT(EMPLOYEENAME)
FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B, TABLE3 C
WHERE A.EMPLOYEEID=B.EMPLOYEEID AND B.EMPLOYEENUM=C.EMPLOYEENUM

**STEP 2 : //SELECT DATA FROM D E and temptable F**
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE4 D, TABLE5 E, temptable F
AND D.EMPLOYEENAME=E.EMPLOYEENAME AND E.EMPLOYEENAME= F.EMPLOYEENAME

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse … A nested query would have been good too… Any other suggestions ?

Comment: The big problem is the `DISTINCT(employeeName)` - If we knew more about his dataset and what he was trying to get out of it, it could maybe be done just as regular joins, bypassing the need for nesting.  Note that, generally, doing things in one go is preferable in SQL, as there are optimizers that work to get the most performant retrieval plans.  Doing things in more than 1 step breaks up the optimizer's plans, which results in increased resource use in most cases.